# Access nested array in Autoform method-update

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to get the value of a nested array from a method that updates an Autoform generated form.

I have a schema set up like this...

```
Schema.ContactDetails = new SimpleSchema({
  orderedBy: {
      type: String,
      label: "Ordered By",
      optional: true,
  },
[...]
)};

Orders.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
[...]
orderDetails: {
      type: Schema.OrderDetails,
      optional: true,
      blackbox: true
  },
[...]
)};
```

I then have an Autoform set up with this...

```
{{#autoForm collection="Orders" id="updateOrderForm" type="method-update" meteormethod="updateOrder" doc=this}}
[...]
{{/autoForm}}
```

And this is the **updateOrder** method...

```
updateOrder: function (doc,doc_id) {
    check(doc, Orders.simpleSchema());
    console.log(doc);

    //Modify doc here

    Orders.update({_id: doc_id}, doc); 
  },
```

The above `console.log(doc);` outputs the following...

```
{   '$set': 
    { createdBy: 'o5Wye6LLMGNXLn7HY',
        createdAt: Sat Apr 09 2016 22:15:27 GMT+1000 (AEST),
        'contactDetails.orderedBy': 'MvCun8p6vxndj3cr8',
        updatedAt: Mon Apr 11 2016 11:47:31 GMT+1000 (AEST) },
    '$unset': 
    { […]
```

My problem is that I need to get the 'contactDetails.orderedBy' value in the updateOrder method but I can't seem to access it. I have tried the following...

`var orderedBy = doc.$set.contactDetails.orderedBy;`

**Exception while invoking method 'updateOrder' TypeError: Cannot read property 'orderedBy' of undefined**

`var orderedBy = doc.$set.'contactDetails.orderedBy';`

**Unexpected token error**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answered here...[Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

and here...[Extract value from object using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543256/extract-value-from-object-using-javascript/36543303#36543303)

```
var orderedBy = doc.$set['contactDetails.orderedBy'];
```