# Extract value from object using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following object...

```
var object = doc.$set;
console.log(object);
```

The console.log above outputs the following...

```
{
  createdBy: 'o5Wye6LLMGNXLn7HY',
  createdAt: Mon Apr 11 2016 15:25:35 GMT+1000 (AEST), 
  'contactDetails.orderedBy': 'MvCun8p6vxndj3cr8',
  updatedAt: Mon Apr 11 2016 18:04:14 GMT+1000 (AEST)
}
```

How can I get the value from `'contactDetails.orderedBy'`?

Where something like this works no problem...

```
var createdBy = doc.$set.createdBy;
```

But this doesn't...

```
var orderedBy = doc.$set.contactDetails.orderedBy;
```

Is there a way that I can use javascript to extract the value instead?
Like maybe convert it to a string and then split it or something along those lines? Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `var orderedBy = doc.$set['contactDetails.orderedBy'];`.

Since an object key is a numeric literal or a valid identifier name, it is necessary to quote the key `contactDetails.orderedBy` to avoid a syntax error.

> Quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal or a valid identifier name.

In the case of `createdBy` key, you could retrieve the value like `object.createdBy` but in the case of `contactDetails.orderedBy` you need to quote, so access it via `object[contactDetails.orderedBy]`.

Comment: You should explain why that would work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11971268)

Comment: right, thanks for the advice. @MuhammedRefaat just edited the answer.

Comment: @petter-pettersson edited!

Comment: now this can be considered as a complete answer

Comment: thank you, always learning...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate object than you need understand the concept of key and value

see this examples

```
var object={
 "iAmFirstKey":'I am value',
 "i.am.second.key":'i am value'
}
```

so In your case your **contacDetails.orderedBy** is not Object inside Object it is an key ("string")

so use like this doc.$set['contacDetails.orderedBy']; you will get your value